# Obtain interface netmask in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, netfilter

I write Linux kernel module with netfilter hook. I want to block any packet that is not from my subnet.

Is there any simple method to get netmask of the interface in kernel-mode? I found only the way to get it using `ioctl()` in user-mode.

Comment: This is going to be tricky, because an interface can have multiple addresses, all with different netmasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty easy way to get it.
Network device is described by `struct net_device`.
[`<linux/netdevice.h>`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.21/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1789):

```
struct net_device {
    ...
    struct in_device __rcu  *ip_ptr;
    ...
```

`net_device` has a pointer to "inet" device (`in_device`).

[`<linux/inetdevice.h>`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.21/source/include/linux/inetdevice.h#L25):

```
struct in_device {
    ...
    struct in_ifaddr    *ifa_list;  /* IP ifaddr chain      */
    ...
```

which finnaly points to chain of [`in_ifaddr`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.21/source/include/linux/inetdevice.h#L137) that contains all the interface info:

```
struct in_ifaddr {
    struct hlist_node   hash;
    struct in_ifaddr    *ifa_next;
    struct in_device    *ifa_dev;
    struct rcu_head     rcu_head;
    __be32              ifa_local;
    __be32              ifa_address;
    __be32              ifa_mask;
    __u32               ifa_rt_priority;
    __be32              ifa_broadcast;
    unsigned char       ifa_scope;
    unsigned char       ifa_prefixlen;
    __u32               ifa_flags;
    char                ifa_label[IFNAMSIZ];

    /* In seconds, relative to tstamp. Expiry is at tstamp + HZ * lft. */
    __u32               ifa_valid_lft;
    __u32               ifa_preferred_lft;
    unsigned long       ifa_cstamp; /* created timestamp */
    unsigned long       ifa_tstamp; /* updated timestamp */
};
```

---

To make my answer more versatile, here is an abstract example (without binding to [netfilter](/questions/tagged/netfilter) and [skb](/questions/tagged/skb) devices logic):

```
struct in_ifaddr *ifa;
struct net_device *dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net, "wlp7s0");
if(!dev) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Can't obtain device\n");
    return;
}

// roughly
rcu_read_lock();
for(ifa = rcu_dereference(dev->ip_ptr->ifa_list);
          ifa;
          ifa = rcu_dereference(ifa->ifa_next))
    printk("address: %pI4, mask: %pI4\n", &ifa->ifa_address, &ifa->ifa_mask);
rcu_read_unlock();
```

From example you can see that you can handle the whole chain(that @larsks mentioned in comment) depending on some specific logic.

P.S. don't forget to include `<linux/netdevice.h>` and `<linux/inetdevice.h>`.